# A Limit of series

Tags: limits

I have to find $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k\cdot \ln\left(k\right)}$$

I tried to write the general term in different ways, to apply squeeze theorem, but I don't get to a result. If possible, I would appreciate a hint using high school knowledge.

Comment: You should first ask yourself whether the limit converges at all.

Comment: **Hint:** Have you tried the integral test ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\ln(k)}>\int_2^n\frac1{x\ln(x)}\ dx=\ln(\log_2(n))\to+\infty$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I made a mistake... edited it now

Comment: @Liviu Ok, I've updated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log2^n}=\frac1{\log2}\cdot\frac1n$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: Just a personal recommendation next time is that you not have the entirety of your answer sitting on a link.